# Is YOLO a good algorithm for defect detection on images?

Tags: neural-networks, object-detection, yolo

I wish to train an algorithm to detect defects on images of labels. These may be such things as scratches, tears and voids.

I would like to try to train a YOLO algorithm to do this, but it is very computationally intensive and requires all training images to have the bounding boxes identified.

Has YOLO been used successfully to detect defects?

Comment: Depending on the details of the problem there may be an easier method. Are the images taken from a consistent orientation? If they are or if transforming them to be the same is not difficult, then a metric based on a simple image difference between the expected/ideal label image and the image to be processed could be pretty effective.

Comment: Unfortunately, the images are not taken from a consistent orientation; the images are on bottles, which rotate to random angles in front of the camera(s).